# Strip query_string

Tags: .htaccess

I want to get rid of some query string on my whole website (explicitly facebook shared/like query which usually begin with fb_action).

I thought about using .htaccess to do that.

I want this: 
Link 1)

```
http://example.com/documents/de_desmarais_en_sirois?fb_action_ids=10151430962018298&fb_action_types=og.likes&fb_source=timeline_og&action_object_map={%2210151430962018298%22%3A157643874359578}&action_type_map={%2210151430962018298%22%3A%22og.likes%22}&action_ref_map=[]
```

to look like:
Link 2)

```
http://example.com/documents/de_desmarais_en_sirois
```

In my .htaccess, I added:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} fb_action
RewriteRule ^(.*) /$1? [R=301,L]
```

But, when I go on the original link, I am directed to my root folder example.com/pages.php, but I want to keep the first part of the URL which is `example.com/documents/de_desmarais_en_sirois`. I don't want to go to my root.

What should I modify/do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you've added those rules to the htaccess file in the `/documents/` directory?

You'll need to remove the leading slash in your rule's target and add a rewrite base:

```
RewriteBase /documents/

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} fb_action
RewriteRule ^(.*) $1? [R=301,L]
```

The query string match could be improved a bit though:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (.*)(^|&)fb_[^&]+(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*) $1?%1%2 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (.*)(^|&)action_[^&]+(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*) $1?%1%2 [R=301,L]
```

To remove only the facebook query string parameters, if you have other parameters that you want to preserve.

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your help,

There is no /document/ directory since everything is rendered dynamically via PHP and mySQL. I use the URL to call specific data in my mySQL database. I can't use RewriteBase. RewriteBase is redirecting all my user to /document/ and I don't want that.  I thought that it would be easier to strip a particular query string from the URL with apache .htaccess, but more I think about it, more I think I'm going to strip the query string via PHP.

Comment: @DominicD It is easy, what you had pretty much does that. But apparently you have another rule or something somewhere that is redirecting to `page.php`

Comment: Oh, thanks. It's true. When I delete the redirection to "pages.php", the query string is stripped correctly, and i see the good url

But, I need that redirection to pages.php... I will need to think about what I will do.

Comment: I succeeded.
I placed the query string redirection before the redirection to pages.php.